# C# Windows Service doesn't invoke an event in another class

Tags: c#, windows-services

Here is my code in class

```
  public FRAME()
    {

       MFileClass media= new MFileClass();
        media.FileNameSet(@"E:\TEST VIDEOS\o.mpg", "");
        media.FilePlayStart();
        media.OnFrame += M_objFile_OnFrame;

    }
    public static void M_objFile_OnFrame(string bsChannelID, object pMFrame)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Trigged");
    }
```

And here is my service code

```
 public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        FRAME frm = new FRAME();
        base.OnStart(args);
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        base.OnStop();
    }
```

M_objFile_OnFrame function doesnt work.
I guess I need to invoke this function but not sure how can invoke to service

Comment: What is `MFileClass`? And how exactly do you think a Windows service is going to play a video when it doesn't even have a desktop?

Comment: Its a object of our SDK.Its rendering to output device card.It doesnt need a interface or something

Comment: Shouldn't you be setting the `OnFrame` callback *before* you start the video - otherwise you might miss the first few frames... It's really hard to answer your actual question though, as we know nothing about what MFileClass does. Does this code work when run interactively? If so, is that a Console application, or WinForms, or something? Are you sure your service is actually working at all - you don't sem to have any logging in it to verify it is working...

Comment: This Code is working properly in WinForm application but in Windows Service Application it doesnt trigger onFrame event.

Comment: How do you know that onFrame is not being triggered. All it is doing is writing to the Console (which, in a Windows Service you will not be able to see!). I think you need to add some proper logging to a file (e.g. with `log4net` or similar) and try again...

Comment: Normally it is writing to a file with streamWriter, " Console.WriteLine("Trigged")" for example

Answer (score -1):

Deneyebilirmisin

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
   timerDelegate = new System.Threading.TimerCallback(CustomStart);
    stateTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(timerDelegate, null, 1000, 1000 * 60 * 1);
}

bool isStart = false;
public void CustomStart(object stateObject)
{
if (isStart) return;
isStart = true;

  FRAME frm = new FRAME();

 }
```

Comment: What exactly is this supposed to do to resolve the OPs problem?

Comment: Selam, CustomStart metodu tetiklenmiyor bu şekilde.